# SimpleDateFormat is parsing to a different Date

Tags: java, date, parsing, simpledateformat

I'm trying to parse a String to a Date using SimpleDateFormat, but It generates a wrong value Date.

```
String dataNascimentoValue = "Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 1970";
SimpleDateFormat converter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");

Date date = new Date();

converter.setLenient(false);
date = converter.parse( dataNascimentoValue ); //at this moment It generates //a wrong Date: Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String formatedDate = formatter.format( date );
```

I already tried to put a Locale at my SimpleDateFormat, but didn't work.
I would like to parse the String to a Date, because I need to format It after.

Any help?

[Screenshot of my try using the Locale.US](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43cut.jpg)

Comment: are you sure about the values in the screenshot ??? How a instance created with `new Date()` can have as value a date with 1969 as year ??

Comment: It didn't have this value, but It takes this value from the line: 

"date = converter.parse( dataNascimentoValue );"

and this is my problem, after this line, When I use this ".parse()" method, the value of my Date takes a wrong value.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.parse ( 
    "Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 1970" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz uuuu" , Locale.CANADA )                    
)
```

## Feature, not a bug

These two strings:

- `Thur Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 1970`
- `Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969`

…represent the **very same moment**, the same point on the timeline. So no problem here; you are seeing correct behavior as documented.

The `EST` refers to the time zones used in the eastern portions of much of the United States and Canada. Such zones are five hours behind UTC (GMT). Midnight minus five hours is 7 PM (19:00) on the previous date. Different [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time), but same moment in the history of the Universe.

One of the many poor design choices in the legacy date-time classes like `Date` is dynamically applying the [JVM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine)’s current default time zone during a call to `toString` generating a representation of a value that is otherwise always in UTC. Very confusing as this behavior creates the illusion of having a time zone when in fact the `Date` is always in UTC. Even more confusing, there actually *is* a time zone deep inside the `Date` used for some internal purposes but without any getter or setter for that zone. This class is an awful mess. Avoid it.

From your report I can deduce that your JVM has a current default time zone in EST.

## Using java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. Avoid these legacy classes; use only java.time classes.

**Always specify a [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html)** when parsing date-time strings. If omitted, your JVM’s current default `Locale` is used in (a) determining the human language such as English for translating the text, and (b) determining the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, and such.

```
String input = "Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 1970";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz uuuu" , Locale.CANADA );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse ( input , f );
```

> zdt.toString(): 1970-01-01T00:00Z[GMT]

You can adjust into other time zones. Apply a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get another [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

**Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name)** in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdtMontreal = zdt.withZoneSameInstant( z );
```

> zdtMontreal.toString(): 1969-12-31T19:00-05:00[America/Montreal]

The `toString` methods on java.time classes are more sensible and clear, using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats when generating a textual representation of the date-time value.

See [live code at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/Jhy5MO).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Basil Bourque, thank you very much for your explanation! 
Unfortunately my project's been made with Java 6, there's some how to "solve" this situation not using new stuffs ?

Comment: @BrunoMori Read my answer more carefully. Pay special attention to second outer bullet under "About java.time" section.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method to parse string to date.

```
 private static final SimpleDateFormat _simpleDateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

public static Date stringToJavaDateOnly(String dateStr)
            throws ParseException {
        return _simpleDateTimeFormat.parse(dateStr);
    }
```

Comment: Incorrect. This format is not even close to that of the input string.